# factory_bot callback in rails 5 throwing exception "TypeError Exception: singleton can't be dumped"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

i am working on a ROR project with ruby 2.6.5 and Rails 5. i have recently upgraded my application from rails 4 to rails 5. I am facing some challenges with rspec while using the factory bot callbacks.

factories/community.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :community do
    mobilehomes {[]}
    photos {[]}
    factory :community_with_homes_and_photos, parent: :community_with_homes do
      after :create do |community, evaluator|
        evaluator.photos.each do |p|
          community.photos << p
        end
      end
    end
  end

  factory :community_with_homes, parent: :community do
   after :create do |community, evaluator|
    evaluator.mobilehomes.each do |m|
      community.mobilehomes << m
    end
   end
 end
end
```

community_spec.rb

```
describe 'photos_and_mobilehomes_photos_count' do
  before :each do
    @photo5 = FactoryBot.create :photo, priority: 4
    @photo6 = FactoryBot.create :photo, priority: 7
    @photo7 = FactoryBot.create :photo, priority: 6
    @photo9 = FactoryBot.create :photo, priority: 9, image_file_size: nil
    @mobilehome1 = FactoryBot.create :mobilehome, photos: [@photo1, @photo2]
    @mobilehome2 = FactoryBot.create :mobilehome, photos: [@photo3, @photo4]
    @mobilehome3 = FactoryBot.create :mobilehome, photos: [@photo8]
    @mobilehome4 = FactoryBot.create :mobilehome

    @community = FactoryBot.create :community_with_homes_and_photos, mobilehomes: [@mobilehome1, @mobilehome2, @mobilehome3, @mobilehome4], photos: [@photo5, @photo6, @photo7, @photo9]
  end

  it 'return the correct number of photos when community and mobilehomes have multiple photos' do
    expect(@community.photos_and_mobilehomes_photos_count).to eq(5)
  end
end
```

I am getting an error with `FactoryBot.create :community_with_homes_and_photos` `TypeError Exception: singleton can't be dumped`. any suggestion how can i fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your `community_with_homes` factory?

Comment: it is also defined in the same file. i have updated my question please check above.

Comment: Hi @BKSpurgeon any suggestions for the above issue?

Comment: unfortunately not, i could not look more into it: looks more to be an rspec issue than anything to do with factory bot.

Comment: ok no probs..thanks for help :)